# post__in not recognizing multiple IDs

Tags: wp-query

I have a bit of an issue regarding post__in

When I do:

```
$newstring = '15,30';
$args = array(
    'post__in' => array($newstring)
);

$loop = new wp_query($args);
```

It only displays the first post (id=15)

But when I do:

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => array(15,30)
);

$loop = new wp_query($args);
```

It works as it should.

The post IDs though is set somewhere. How do I solve this one using the first scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a PHP than a WordPress issue:

If `$newstring = '15,30';` then `array($newstring)` is an array containing this string.

If you `print_r( array($newstring) )`, it looks like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => 15,30
)
```

Which is not the same as `array(15,30)`.

What you want to do instead is:

```
$newstring = '15,30';
$args = array(
    'post__in' => explode(',', $newstring)
);
```

`print_r( explode(',', $newstring) )` will look like:

```
Array (
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 30
)
```

Which now is exactly the same as `array(15,30)`.

See [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to better understand how this function works.

Comment: Hey thanks. It solved the issue. I tried this before but I still enclosed the exploded items in an array, which, it turns out, wasn't necessary